# If the system supports 64bit word then how many words can be stored in the RAM? Also how many bits will be required to address each Word uniquely?

Tags: cpu-architecture

a)  Suppose there is a RAM of size 4GB installed in an intel Core i5 computer. If the system supports 64bit word then how many words can be stored in the RAM? Also how many bits will be required to address each Word uniquely?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: In x86-64 documentation and technical terminology, a "word" means 16 bits.  Remember that x86-64 evolved out of 8086.  A qword is 64 bits.  Also, x86-64 is byte addressable, so "bits to address each word uniquely" is only relevant for software using spare bits in pointers, not for hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables to this question.  How big are the words?  How much RAM does Microsoft let Word use before it starts swapping data in a pagefile?  Is any compression used?

If we assume that Word has access to all 4GB of RAM (the OS, and Word aren't using any in this situation), that there is no pagefile to dump to, and no compression going on in the background, we can do some simple math to find out. We know that typically a single ascii character takes up 1 byte of memory, and that there are 1024 bytes in a KB, 1024 KB in a MB, and so on.  So, we just multiply until we get to 4GB worth of bytes. 1024 Bytes X 1024 KB X 1024 MB X 4 GB = 4,294,967,296 ascii characters.

Coincidentally, that's the maximum number of possible 32-bit addresses in 32bit systems, and why 32bit systems were unable to support more than 4GB of RAM without Physical Address Extension (PAE). With so little RAM, it doesn't matter that the program is 64bit, it just means it can handle addressing and integers larger than that if the RAM is available.

I hope that helps you in some way! I'm kind of concerned that you are having to worry about the maximum number of words that can be stored in 4GB.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question as asking about how many copies of MS Word could run on a computer.  Given the cpu-architecture tag, I think it's clear the question is asking about how many 64-bit chunks (aka "machine words") can be stored in memory, despite that fact that in x86-64 we call that a qword (because a "word" is still 16 bits, as in `paddw`).  Not English words in a word processor in user-space under an OS.  That interpretation of 64-bit-word makes the question unambiguous (and trivial), which is a point in its favour.

Comment: Oh!  I definitely misunderstood the question then. Thank you. I'm still concerned that Atif has to worry about this though.

Comment: The point of a homework question like this is to see if students understood the basic definitions, like size of a byte, and 8 bytes in a 64-bit word, and can turn those words into `2^32 / 2^3 = 2^29` qwords fit in DRAM.  (assuming (often unlike a real i5 system) that it's all actually accessible in physical address space, not overlapped by device memory or BIOS). Also that 29 address bits uniquely identify one of 2^29 qwords, so you could use the low 3 bits of pointers for tagged-pointers or something.  i.e. it's a basic math / powers of 2 problem dressed up as computer architecture.

Comment: It's not something anyone would ever need for using a computer, just for learning about how they're designed.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you again Peter for clearing that up. I was solidly confused and horrified that this needed answering. I never thought of asking homework questions on community sites before, and now I've also learned to pay attention to the tags.  I'll just uh...sheepishly exit stage right.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately a lot of people want other people to do their homework for them, so much so that SO has a policy for homework questions. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)  (Most importantly, an attempt is required.  That's the part that filters out many questions, like this one, so we can just downvote them and stop them clogging up our search results.)